# ZF2 Get Current Module Name in Abstract Class

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is it possible in ZF2 to get the current module in a Abstract class ? I know there is a function getModuleName() in the ModuleEvent but I'm unable to use that.

Or do I need to strip it myself ?

Answer (score 0):

`getModuleName()` in `ModuleEvent` just can be used if you listen `loadModule.resolve`.

I just prefer to extract your module name from your `namespace`. If your module have `\` inside it (eg: `Zend\Log`), the module name usually is the latest part.

```
$names = explode("\\", __NAMESPACE__);
$moduleName = end($names);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out last night the same but I wonder if ZF3 didn't remove __NAMESPACE__

There are people that dislike __NAMESPACE__ and say you should not use it, so if you don't you have an issue with this way of getting the modulename ?

Comment: which one did you used? ZF2 or ZF3?

Comment: I'm still on ZF2 but will be moving to ZF3 in some time, so upgrade to it.

Comment: I see. `__NAMESPACE__` is **PHP Constant**, so ZF3 will not remove it.

Comment: /me sends love! you are true so thanks for reporting back! I thought it was odd to use.